# React Native - How to change an object's value for a key in props

Tags: javascript, android, listview, react-native

So I have a ListView in react native, the ListView is populated through the code:

```
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.ID !== r2.ID});
   ...
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.businesses),
   ...
   }
```

The list is inside a Navigator naturally, so when you pick an item it would push the navigator's view to show that item-View. Inside the item-View, there's a button that should change the item's data.

What happens, is that the data that was changed would be sent to server, but locally, when the item-View is dismissed, the local representation of the data is remained just as it was received from the server in the first place.

for example, the button is an "Active" button. 
When received from the server it was off. 
Now, user presses on "Active" - the button turns white, and the server is informed.
- All is ok up to here.
- Now, the user dismisses the item-View.
- Taps the same item again. 
- "Active" button is off again (because the ListView's datasource was not updated.

How do I update that single item's property inside ListView, so when I call it again, the button will be activated?
Tx